# $_GET check license tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question how to do this, so that checks the tables with $ _GET in mysql. I have a script.

```
<?php
require_once 'inc/config.php';
if (isset($_GET['ip'])) {
    $ip = trim($_GET['ip']);
    $code = trim($_POST['code']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM license WHERE ip=? AND code=?";

    $db = new MySQL($dbc['host'], $dbc['user'], $dbc['password'], $dbc['database']);
    $stm = $db->dbConn->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array($ip, $code));
    echo "1";
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
$dbc['host'] = "localhost";
$dbc['user'] = "admin_bf2mod";
$dbc['password'] = "LwNMtIwiz8";
$dbc['database'] = "admin_bf2mod";
?>
```

I want to scan from the table if the IP is correct but the code is not it shows 1 if the code and the ip is good it shows 0 if the code is

Comment: Well, you need to look at the result set from your executed query and see if any rows were found. Just executing a query does not tell you anything you need to look at the results

Comment: When I go to the php license.php?ip=127.0.0.1&?code=ba27761fa71375eeb4da66e57a188d08 nothing shows